# SOAP query getting value from parent

Tags: soql, soap-api, soap, query

I tried to read [this page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) to learn about joins, but for some reason I'm not doing it correctly.

I have two tables:

- Member_Project_Junction__c which has the value Member_First_Name__c
- Contact which has the value Industry__c

I want to do a query that by the id of the Member_Project_Junction__c I can get the Industry. I've tried:

```
    SELECT Member_Project_Junction__c , Contact__r.Industry__c 
    FROM Member_Project_Junction__c 
    WHERE Id ='1'

    SELECT Member_Project_Junction__c , (SELECT Industry__c FROM Contact__r)  
    FROM Member_Project_Junction__c 
    WHERE Id ='1'
```

As you can imagine, none of them work. What am I doing wrong? I'm using PHP and accessing it through SOAP. Thanks!

Comment: How is Member_Project_Junction related to Contact?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I was just told that I could get the industry for the Member from the Contact table, thats all I was told

Comment: @raygo Perhaps it'd help if you described the error you're getting when you try these two queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely this query:

```
SELECT Id, Contact__r.Industry__c FROM Member_Project_Junction__c
```